# How can i use php8 attributes instead of annotations in doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, php-8

This is what I would like to use:

```php
#[ORM\Column(type: "string")]
```

instead of this:

```php
/**
 *  @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
(error: Class 'Column' is not annotated with 'Attribute' )
```

Is it because Doctrine does not support it yet, or am I missing something?

Comment: What use-case do you have for needing to use annotations like that? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: In case you have hundreds of annotations and want to convert them attributes, you might prefer to automate this. I wrote an open-source tool Rector that handles this upgrade for you: https://getrector.org/blog/how-to-upgrade-annotations-to-attributes

Answer (score 67, accepted):

As @Seb33300 says, yes, it's [now possible](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/attributes-reference.html) in Doctrine ORM 2.9. But for Symfony you need to do a little bit more than that. Here is a full list of steps to upgrade:

1. Upgrade Doctrine ORM: `"doctrine/orm": "^2.9"`.
2. Upgrade Doctrine Bundle: `"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.4"`.
3. Set `doctrine.orm.mappings.App.type: attribute` (by default it's set to `annotation`):

   ```yaml
   # config/packages/doctrine.yaml

   doctrine:
     orm:
       mappings:
         App:
           type: attribute
   ```
4. Apply similar changes to your entities:

   ```
   --- Dummy.php.old     Mon Jun 07 00:00:00 2021
   +++ Dummy.php         Mon Jun 07 00:00:00 2021
   @@ -7,15 +7,11 @@
    use App\Repository\DummyRepository;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

   -/**
   - * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass = DummyRepository::class)
   - */
   +#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: DummyRepository::class)]
    class Dummy
    {
   -    /**
   -     * @ORM\Id
   -     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
   -     * @ORM\Column(type = 'integer')
   -     */
   +    #[ORM\Id]
   +    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
   +    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
        private $id;
    }
   ```

Comment: The change from "annotation" to "attribute" is critical. Thank you for documenting it.

Comment: Is there any way to allow both, to have a smooth migration for the existing attributes?

Comment: @the_nuts Could you able to find a way to allow both ? Please let me know

Comment: @nas yes, I created another directory, so what I have in `Entity` is still with annotation, and what I have in `EntAttribs` (couldn't find a better name lol) is with attributes: https://pastebin.com/VS1jGD8x

Answer (score 16):

**EDIT: Doctrine 2.9 [is now released](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/releases) with PHP 8 attributes support!**

PHP 8 annotations have been merged in Doctrine ORM `2.9.x` branch which is not released yet:
https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/8266

Here is the documentation reference related to this feature:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/attributes-reference.html